# How to permit users to add more items to a multivalue field conditionally?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm working on a publication management site and need a multivalue field collection (which contains several file upload fields). Our authors can upload multiple versions of their publication but only after reviewers (or managers) allow it. Basically I would like to hide the "add another item" button and show if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place this in a custom module replacing what is given in CAPITAL letters:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'CONTENT_TYPE_node_form') {
    if (CONDITIONS) {
      unset($form['field_files_collection'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['add_more']);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it'd be a good 'wireframe' solution for my problem. However, the 'CONDITIONS' is the tricky part (for me): In this case the condition would be a workflow state of a referenced node.

Comment: Well, your question contained not more than `if certain conditions are met`, so please accept my answer if it is right as the principle approach and work through your conditions further. Or edit your question and provide detailed information on `condition` part, so your question would become answerable.